# Use directory name in RewriteRule statement

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I want to create a RewriteCond / RewriteRule combination, obtaining this result:

> www.domain.com/dir1/old_file.php?a=1 => www.domain.com/dir1/a/1
>
> www.domain.com/dir2/dir3/old_file.php?b=2 => www.domain.com/dir2/dir3/b/2

Any hint?

---

I'm trying something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)\=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/%1/%2? [R=301,L]
```

But the result is not what I looking for:

```
curl -I "http://localhost/testsite/web/dir1/a.php?b=c"

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Thu, 26 Jan 2012 10:36:15 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.20 (Ubuntu)
Location: http://localhost/dir1/a.php/b/c
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

The .htacces is located in `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/testsite/web/.htaccess`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(.*)` in your `RewriteRule` matches the requested URL *minus* the location of the `.htaccess` file.

If `/testsite/web/foo/bar` is the requested URL and the file is located in `/testsite/web/`, then `/foo/bar` is matched only.

You'll need to adjust that rewrite rule like so:

```
RewriteRule (.*) /testsite/web/$1/%1/%2 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to do it on the web server? Since the old links are pointing to PHP scripts, you could use a:

```
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: http://www.newplace.com/");
```

Since you need to determine the new location from the current one, you will need to use something like:

```
$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
```

Then perform your REGEX against this string to determine the true location of the redirect.

Comment: It could be a solution, but I prefer not to use old scripts and remove them, because I'm migrating the whole website to another structure.

Comment: I'm guessing you are switching to using CodeIgniter or similar, based on your new URI's. Unfortunately I am not familiar with Apache rewrite rules so I can't be of further help.